# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I am working on horizontalscrollview with swipe the screen horizontally, I want to add view dynamically on present view but its not happening, What I did wrong in the code.. Here is my code

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {

        private GestureDetector gDetector;
            private MyHorizontalScrollView scrollView;
            private View app;

            @TargetApi(11)      
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
                setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample, null));
//here I edited..
     scrollView = (MyHorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScrollView_);
                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
                scrollView.addView(layout);

                ListView listView = new ListView(this);
                initListView(this, listView, "Item ", 30, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
                layout.addView(listView);

                //setContentView(R.layout.sample);
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
                    getActionBar().hide();
                }
                findViewById(R.id.sample_button).setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                int width = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                                SlideoutActivity.prepare(MainActivity.this, R.id.inner_content, width);
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                        MenuActivity.class));
                                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                            }
                        });
                gDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
            }
            public static void initListView(Context context, ListView listView,String prefix, int numItems, int layout ){

                // By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.
                String[] arr = new String[numItems];
                for(int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){

                    arr[i] = prefix + (i +1);
                }

                listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, layout, arr));
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
                        Context context = view.getContext();

                        String msg = "item[" + position + "]= " + parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);

                        Toast.makeText(context, msg, 1000).show();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float xVelocity,
                    float yVelocity) {
                if(start.getRawX() < finish.getRawX()){

                    /*((ViewGroup)scrollView.getParent()).removeView(scrollView);

                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

                    scrollView = (MyHorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScrollView_);
                    app = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_app, null);

                    ListView listView = (ListView) app.findViewById(R.id.list);
                    initListView(this, listView, "Item ", 30, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
                    setContentView(listView);*/

                    TextView toolbartext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
                    toolbartext.setText("New text for samples from left to right");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "from left to right Swipe working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    TextView toolbartext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
                    toolbartext.setText("New text for samples from right to left");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "from right to left Swipe working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2,
                    float arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return gDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        }
```

and her is my logcat content..

```
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1970)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1865)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1845)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:217)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1658)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.example.sample.MainActivity.onFling(MainActivity.java:105)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:568)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.example.sample.MainActivity.onTouchEvent(MainActivity.java:146)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2089)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-29 11:00:22.732: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were trying to `addViews` to the `HorizontalScrollView`.

A `ScrollView` can only have one child.

So, you can add a `Linear/RelativeLayout` to the `ScrollView` first and then add other `views` to this `layout`.

**Code:**

Something like this

```
HorizontalScrollView hsv = findViewById(R.id.mHSV);
//add a linear layout to your scrollview
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout (this);
hsv.addView(layout);
//add the remaining views to this linear layout
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
layout.addView(textView);
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast replay..How can I add, I am newbie to android please elaborate me or if you have any small code example please drop here

Comment: wow..cool...! you just done it..:) but another question here how can I add swipe action in Horizontalscrollview..??